# Detecting new struct initialization

Tags: struct, rust, rust-cargo

I'm coming from mostly OOP languages, so getting this concept to work in Rust kinda seems hard. I want to implement a basic counter that keeps count of how many "instances" I've made of that type, and keep them in a vector for later use.

I've tried many different things, first was making a static vector variable, but that cant be done due to it not allowing static stuff that have destructors.

This was my first try:

```
struct Entity {
    name: String,
}

struct EntityCounter {
    count: i64,
}

impl Entity {
    pub fn init() {
        let counter = EntityCounter { count: 0 };
    }

    pub fn new(name: String) {
        println!("Entity named {} was made.", name);
        counter += 1; // counter variable unaccessable (is there a way to make it global to the struct (?..idek))
    }
}

fn main() {
    Entity::init();
    Entity::new("Hello".to_string());
}
```

Second:

```
struct Entity {
    name: String,
    counter: i32,
}

impl Entity {
    pub fn new(self) {
        println!("Entity named {} was made.", self.name);
        self.counter = self.counter + 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    Entity::new(Entity { name: "Test".to_string() });
}
```

None of those work, I was just trying out some concepts on how I could be able to implement such a feature.

Comment: In addition to DK's very insightful points, note that your code would have intrinsic problems with multithreaded programs.

Comment: You're asking for global, mutable variables, to which Rust takes the principled approach of blowing raspberries and hitting you with a wet sock. A local approach like a builder object (eg. `EntityCache`) with a `new_entity` method would fit Rust a *lot* better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems appear to be somewhat more fundamental than what you describe.  You're kind of throwing code at the wall to see what sticks, and that's simply not going to get you anywhere.  I'd recommend reading [the Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) completely before continuing.  If you don't understand something in it, ask about it.  As it stands, you're demonstrating you don't understand variable scoping, return types, how instance construction works, how statics work, and how parameters are passed.  That's a *really* shaky base to try and build any understanding on.

In this particular case, you're asking for something that's *deliberately* not straightforward.  You say you want a counter *and* a vector of instances.  The counter is simple enough, but a vector of instances?  Rust doesn't allow easy sharing like other languages, so how you go about doing that depends *heavily* on what it is you're *actually* intending to use this for.

What follows is a *very* rough guess at something that's *maybe* vaguely similar to what you want.

````rust
/*!
Because we need the `lazy_static` crate, you need to add the following to your
`Cargo.toml` file:

```cargo
[dependencies]
lazy_static = "0.2.1"
```
*/

#[macro_use] extern crate lazy_static;

mod entity {
    use std::sync::{Arc, Weak, Mutex};
    use std::sync::atomic;

    pub struct Entity {
        pub name: String,
    }

    impl Entity {
        pub fn new(name: String) -> Arc<Self> {
            println!("Entity named {} was made.", name);
            let ent = Arc::new(Entity {
                name: name,
            });
            bump_counter();
            remember_instance(ent.clone());
            ent
        }
    }

    /*
    The counter is simple enough, though I'm not clear on *why* you even want
    it in the first place.  You don't appear to be using it for anything...
    */
    static COUNTER: atomic::AtomicUsize = atomic::ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT;

    fn bump_counter() {
        // Add one using the most conservative ordering.
        COUNTER.fetch_add(1, atomic::Ordering::SeqCst);
    }

    pub fn get_counter() -> usize {
        COUNTER.load(atomic::Ordering::SeqCst)
    }

    /*
    There are *multiple* ways of doing this part, and you simply haven't given
    enough information on what it is you're trying to do.  This is, at best,
    a *very* rough guess.

    `Mutex` lets us safely mutate the vector from any thread, and `Weak`
    prevents `INSTANCES` from keeping every instance alive *forever*.  I mean,
    maybe you *want* that, but you didn't specify.

    Note that I haven't written a "cleanup" function here to remove dead weak
    references.
    */
    lazy_static! {
        static ref INSTANCES: Mutex<Vec<Weak<Entity>>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
    }

    fn remember_instance(entity: Arc<Entity>) {
        // Downgrade to a weak reference.  Type constraint is just for clarity.
        let entity: Weak<Entity> = Arc::downgrade(&entity);
        INSTANCES
            // Lock mutex
            .lock().expect("INSTANCES mutex was poisoned")
            // Push entity
            .push(entity);
    }

    pub fn get_instances() -> Vec<Arc<Entity>> {
        /*
        This is about as inefficient as I could write this, but again, without
        knowing your access patterns, I can't really do any better.
        */
        INSTANCES
            // Lock mutex
            .lock().expect("INSTANCES mutex was poisoned")
            // Get a borrowing iterator from the Vec.
            .iter()
            /*
            Convert each `&Weak<Entity>` into a fresh `Arc<Entity>`.  If we
            couldn't (because the weak ref is dead), just drop that element.
            */
            .filter_map(|weak_entity| weak_entity.upgrade())
            // Collect into a new `Vec`.
            .collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    use entity::Entity;

    let e0 = Entity::new("Entity 0".to_string());
    println!("e0: {}", e0.name);
    {
        let e1 = Entity::new("Entity 1".to_string());
        println!("e1: {}", e1.name);

        /*
        `e1` is dropped here, which should cause the underlying `Entity` to
        stop existing, since there are no other "strong" references to it.
        */
    }
    let e2 = Entity::new("Entity 2".to_string());
    println!("e2: {}", e2.name);

    println!("Counter: {}", entity::get_counter());

    println!("Instances:");
    for ent in entity::get_instances() {
        println!("- {}", ent.name);
    }
}
````

Comment: Im not particularly using anything, i was testing out stuff, these are hard after doing python, php and javaj, thats why i asked how hard it would be to implement something like this in Rust. (because in java i could just use a global  ArrayList and place every entity there). Thanks.

Comment: There is a deprecation for the `ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT` now it becomes: 
`static COUNTER: atomic::AtomicUsize = atomic::AtomicUsize::new(0);`