# Object counter (num. instances of object that exist)

Tags: rust

Is there a way to have a generic object counter in rust? In C++, [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Object_counter) shows a really clean way to do this.

The idea I had to do this was to have a `struct ObjectCounter<T> {}` that implements new() and drop(). And to keep a static map from `TypeId` to `u64` to keep track of the count. [Here is the full implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=489a61c6808c809db6290d5897dfa574).

Is there a cleaner way to implement this? Is there a way to avoid the global map and just associate an `AtomicU64` with each type that requires counting?

Note that I'm just doing this for fun - I don't have a real-world use-case for this right now.

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Master, how many instances of truth are there. "True", the master replied. But master, that's not an answer. "true as u32" the master said. The student was enlightened.

Comment: possibility for duplication 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993255/detecting-new-struct-initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this a bit more elegant with a trait `Counting`:

```
pub trait Counting : Sized  where Self:'static{
  fn new() -> Self {
    //increase the global static counter
  }
  fn new_instance() -> Self;

  fn destroy(&self) {
    //decrease the global static counter
  }

  fn count() -> u64 {
    //return the global static counter
  }
}
```

The parts in common could be implemented as in your full implementation.

Choosing this way, your struct will have to implement `Counting` and `Drop`:

```
struct Struct1 {}

impl Counting for Struct1 {
  fn new_instance() -> Struct1 {
    Struct1 {}
  }
}

impl Drop for Struct1 {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    self.destroy();
  }
}
```

and if you are familiar with macros the lower could be probably shortened by:

```
#[derive(Counting)] //the implementation is left to the reader
struct Struct1 {}
```

[The full implementation (without the macro part) would be here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15b94d03cd534d4c0cc93b6cc98924ab)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think the link to your full implementation is broken.

One small issue I see with this is that now each user of Counting will have to remember to call destroy() in the drop method. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The code for `Drop` is always the same, so a macro (I mentioned it above) could add it. I also tried out a blanket implementation of Drop for all types that implement counting, but this is conflicting with other blanket implementations (but maybe someone finds a solution to get it to work).
But after reviewing it there is another problem: The `new_instance()` or `new()`  method do only work for structs without data - but real-world structs can be created with arguments. I hope someone has an idea how to intercept the rust construction mechanism in another way.